# Configure Protractor to ignore resources if it takes too long to respond

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, protractor

I am using protractor to automate a few tests on a website.
After angular and all other scripts and css loads, there is a referenced third-party resource that takes too long to load. While protractor is waiting for that resource to finish loading, the unit test fails due to timeout.
Is there a way to skip loading resources after a few seconds and continue with the task. (PS: increasing timeout limit is not the solution for me)

`it('abc', function() {
    //This is fine
    browser.driver.get('http://loginurl.com');
    browser.driver.findElement(by.name('username')).sendKeys('username');
    browser.driver.findElement(by.name('password')).sendKeys('password');
    browser.driver.findElement(by.name('loginsubmit')).click();
    browser.sleep(3000);
    //This has problems
    browser.driver.get('http://contenturl.com');
    browser.sleep(1000);
    browser.executeScript("window.stop();");
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('post_reply')).click();
    browser.sleep(1000);
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('postmessage')).sendKeys('aaabbbcc');
    browser.driver.findElement(by.id('postsubmit')).click();
    browser.pause();
    //browser.get('http://url.com');
    //element(by.id("post_replytmp")).click();
    });`

Answer (score 0):

You can execute the [`window.stop()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/stop) on the page load timeout:

```
browser.get("url", 10000).then(function () {}, function () {
    browser.executeScript("window.stop();");
});
```

(not tested).

Comment: For me, this line does not execute unless the page is fully loaded.
here is my code 
`browser.driver.get('url');
    browser.sleep(3000);
    browser.executeScript("window.stop();");`

Comment: @maxiC ah, gotcha. Could you please try the updated version of the answer? Thanks!

Comment: thanks. It still seems to be waiting for the page to finish. I will dig around more. Thanks again!